Auditing/Monitoring the DBA
We have a customer that would like to make sure that certain tables are not tampered with by their DBAs for compliance reasons.
From my understanding their DBAs either do have or are able to run with sysadmin permissions, so I feel with any level of auditing or triggers, this will not be possible as they can 'tamper' with any auditing methods.
Is there a way to guarantee a sysadmin does not tamper with records (beyond not granting sysadmin) or to monitor any modifications without compromise?
Thanks in advance

What version of SQL Server?

@MartinSmith I think it's SQL 2019

That's a shame

Thanks for sharing that! It'll be a super useful feature

Ledger is a step in the right direction, but the answer unfortunately is there is no foolproof way to meet your goal, so long as someone has SysAdmin access. Even with Ledger tables, a SysAdmin could surely restore an older backup over the live database which is a roundabout way of altering the data of the Ledger table. In fact, said DBA could go one step further by restoring a backup to another SQL Server instance they control, make whatever changes they wanted, back that database up, and restore it back to the live server's database. The solution is to hire DBAs you can trust.

Set up an Audit to write to a file share and deny the sysadmins access to that share.
The sysadmin can tamper/stop the audit, but that action itself can be audited

You might want to try a 3rd party tool like Apex SQL Audit. It will record any changes made to the database and can be configured to send alerts, daily reports, etc.

We've spent a lot of time thinking about this question. Depending on the precise form of tampering possible in your case and what scenarios you're looking to prevent, there are a few solutions you may want to consider.
@J.D. is exactly right, the problem with the Ledger solution is that verifying backup integrity may bring you back to square one.
You need some 3rd party source of truth on what a prior good state of the database is so that any differences between the good state and current state can be easily identified. This would make any tampering quickly evident.
Some ways to do this at scale are:

Enterprise organizational model where another set of sysadmins in another department are in charge of maintaining backups (or are the sysadmins of the Ledger-style provenance database)
RFC3161 timestamps for your backups (e.g. https://knowledge.digicert.com/general-information/rfc3161-compliant-time-stamp-authority-server)
Blockchain-based stamps via an automated data stamping solution like validityBase (https://docs.vbase.com/getting-started/dataset-commitments). << Note: I work for this company.>>

Which approach is best would depend your client’s capabilities and preferences.
